# Database Design: Transactional design approach

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a basic but very important transactional database design question. I am designing a transactional database that models four real world entities. Each of these entities has an Owner attribute. When a user creates an entity they will specify who the owner of that entity is. This owner can then change at a later date. While theoretically each owner could be different based on the real world scenarios I expect a small number of owners with the same person owning many of the entities.

In the current design the Owner is stored in a basic Owner table and each of the 4 entities is joined to this same Owner table with the Owner ID being the FK in the entity tables. The owner table is basic; it is OwnerID and Name, where OwnerID is the PK, and the OwnerID is a FK in each of the entity tables.

I have a sneaky feeling this is the wrong approach for a Transactional database and that the approach I am taking is as if I was designing a reporting database (star schema) with the Owner being a dimension of these entities. In the current design it looks like the Entity belongs to the Owner as opposed to the opposite way around.

The alternative is that I either store the Owner on each entity table or create Owner specific table for each entity i.e. table EntityOne which then joins to EntityOneOwner where the EntityID is a FK in the EntityOneOwner table.

Hope I am making sense here. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't see the problem. If the entity **must have** an owner, the FK constraint (from entity->owner) would be **NOT NULL**. If owners should exist that don't own anything is a different question (and hardly important) Should customers be allowed that did not order anything?

Comment: That is thing I didn't know if it was a problem or not but based on the replies it sounds like it is not :). No owners cannot exist unless they own one of the entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is the correct approach for an OLTP database - sounds like a good normalized database.

A reporting database (OLAP, for instance) would be denormalized with the owner Name being repeated in the different tables for ease of querying.